# DevExtreme Autocomplete does not filter

Tags: autocomplete, devextreme, devexpress-mvc

I'm using DevExtreme and have a problem with Autocomplete widget.

This is my code to create autocomplete

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().AutocompleteFor(m => m.CityName)
    .ID("edCity")
    .Placeholder(Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.CityName).ToString())
    .MinSearchLength(3)
    .SearchTimeout(500)
    .ValueExpr("Name")
    .DataSource(d => d.WebApi().Controller("LNAX").LoadAction("Cities").Key("Name").LoadParams(new { id = 5 }))
)
```

This is the City class

```
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I start typing in the exit box. it show all the Cities in the drop-down list. My expectation is show a filtered list beased on what I have typed in.

What is missing in configuring the widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use javascript to filter the datasource when user types in inside the edit box

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().AutocompleteFor(m => m.CityName)
    .ID("edCity")
    .Placeholder(Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.CityName).ToString())
    .MinSearchLength(3)
    .SearchTimeout(500)
    .ValueExpr("Name")
    .DataSource(d => d.WebApi().Controller("LNAX").LoadAction("Cities").Key("Name").LoadParams(new { id = 5 }))
    .OnValueChanged("onCityChange") // add this line
)
```

and then have a javascript like this:

```
function onCityChange(e) {
    if (e.value.length >= 3) {
        var filter = e.value;
        var stateId = 5
        autocompleteData = new DevExpress.data.DataSource(/*a url that returns filtered data based on stateId and filter variables*/);
        autocompleteData.load();
        // set the new data source to your dxAutocomplete widget
        $("#edCity").dxAutocomplete("instance").option("dataSource", autocompleteData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!. Your answer helped me to write my code.

Comment: This will ignore the `searchTimeout` setting -- the `dataSource` reload happens after every single letter is typed (after the 3rd letter), even if there is no pause.

Answer (score 1):

I took a different approach to resolving this issue.

```
i.AddSimpleFor(m => m.ams_Vendor).Editor(e => e.Autocomplete().DataSource(ds => ds.Mvc().Controller("AutoComplete").LoadAction("Vendor").LoadParams(new { jadeId = 52 })).ShowClearButton(true));
```

I added the additional filtering I wanted for the autocomplete in the LoadParams. This passes jadeId in the query string.  It does not add it to the filter.

In my autocomplete controller I added the jadeId variable in the method.

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Vendor(DataSourceLoadOptions loadOptions, [FromQuery(Name = "jadeId")] int jadeId)
        {
            return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataSourceLoader.Load(GetDistinctValues("AMS_Vendor", jadeId), loadOptions)), "application/json");
    }
```

Then in my GetDistinctValues method (using DevExpress' XPO) I added the jadefilter criteria.

```
private List<string> GetDistinctValues(string fieldname, int jadeId)
        {
            // get the distinct values from 
            List<string> model = new List<string>();

            XPView view = new XPView(_uow, typeof(JadeModels));
            view.AddProperty(fieldname, fieldname, true, true, SortDirection.Ascending);
            CriteriaOperator criteria = new NotOperator(new NullOperator(fieldname));
            CriteriaOperator jadefilter = new BinaryOperator("JadeId", jadeId);
            view.Criteria = new GroupOperator(GroupOperatorType.And, criteria, jadefilter);

            foreach (ViewRecord item in view)
            {
                model.Add(item[0].ToString());
            }
            return model;
        }
```

For me, this solution should work perfectly. I would never need to get autocomplete values without the jadeId filter.  Your mileage may vary. For me not adding more javascript is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

The Autocomplete widget does implement this behavior, although I found several posts on the DevExtreme support site that say you have to use the Lookup widget instead.

The key is that the Autocomplete widget expects your datasource to look for and use `$filter` and other parameters to return the correct filtered list. You can add your own parameters as well; see below.

There's a demo showing this on the DevExpress site: 
https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Autocomplete/Overview/jQuery/Light/

It's the State field under "Custom Item Template and Data Source Usage" -- even though the dataset is trivial (the list of 50 US states) it is actually querying a remote datasource and returning a filtered list.  Here's the demo code (JQuery, see the demo link for other flavors):

```
$("#state").dxAutocomplete({
    dataSource: new DevExpress.data.ODataStore({
        url: "https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/DevAV/odata/States?$select=Sate_ID,State_Long,State_Short",
        key: "Sate_ID",
        keyType: "Int32"
    }),
    placeholder: "Type state name...",
    valueExpr: "State_Long",
    itemTemplate: function(data) {
        return $("<div>" + data.State_Long + 
            " (" + data.State_Short + ")" + "</div>");
    },
    onValueChanged: function(data) {
        state = data.value;
        updateEmployeeInfo();
    }
});
```

Type 'ala' in the state field, and notice this network request occurs (I viewed the request using Chrome Developer Tools, Network tab).

https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/DevAV/odata/States?$select=Sate_ID,State_Long,State_Short&$top=10&$filter=(substringof(%27ala%27%2Ctolower(State_Long)))

This returns the expected list of only two states by observing the `$top`and `$filter` parameters.

You can also add your own parameters -- which is what I did because I couldn't handle `$` in parameter names.  Just use `params` in the datasource's `beforeSend` event:

```
    dataSource: new DevExpress.data.ODataStore({
        url: "https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/DevAV/odata/States?$select=Sate_ID,State_Long,State_Short",
        key: "Sate_ID",
        keyType: "Int32"            
        beforeSend: function (e) {
            console.log(e.params) // Show original params
            e.params.SearchTerm = $("#state").val()
            e.params.Limit = 10
            console.log(e.params) // There's my new params
        }
    })
```

Now the datasource could use the parameters `SearchTerm` and `Limit` and ignore the others.